# Access one element from ManyToMany Field in models.py in order to construct get_absolute_url

Tags: django, url, many-to-many, models

I have this in my models.py:

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
         return "/subject/%s/graphs/%s/" % (self.subject, self.slug)
```

where subject and slug are accordingly:

```
subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=True)
```

and I know that the approach I have in the `get_absolute_url()` function is wrong, and returns the list of *Subject* objects.

I want to access only one element (it doesn't matter which one it will be) so I can construct the url of the graph, but I don't know how to do that. I've tried several things, but they don't work.

**Update:**

Got the solution:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
         for e in self.subject.all():
             return "/subject/%s/graphs/%s/" % (e.url_id, self.slug)
```

It works like this. There is no need to check if there is a subject because there will always be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ManyToMany` field is a relationship that returns a `QuerySet` of multiple objects, so you need to choose one object from that queryset to use to construct your URL. You can do this many ways.

For example, if your Subject model has a date field, you could return [the `latest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) Subject:

```
return "/subject/%s/graphs/%s/" % (self.subject.all().latest("my_date_field"), self.slug)
```

alternatively, you could just try and get the first Subject of the queryset:

```
return "/subject/%s/graphs/%s/" % (self.subject.all()[0], self.slug)
```

Have a look at the [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) to see what might be most appropriate for you.

You should also remember that your `get_absolute_url` method will likely throw an exception if there are no Subject objects associated with your model so you should do:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    try:
        return "/subject..."
    except:
        return "/another-url/"
```

Comment: I don't have a date field. For some reason the second option doesn't work, get_absolute_url returns empty in that case. Do you maybe know why? There is always a subject, usually more than one.

Comment: I modified your answer a bit and got the solution:
`def get_absolute_url(self):
         for e in self.subject.all():
             return "/subject/%s/graphs/%s/" % (e.url_id, self.slug)`

Thanks.